# How to recover lost Google Chrome icons after deletion of the configuration?

Tags: google-chrome

I had deleted google-chrome configuration (sudo rm -r ~/.config/google-chrome) and uninstalled google chrome. After re-installing it I noticed that the extension are not working and there icons are missing.

How do I make then sync again or make then work again??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by copying the folder "~/.config/google-chrome" from another laptop and deleting singleton-lock and singleton-socket file.